# Result of "regsub -all -- (a+)(ba*) aabaabxab {z\2} x"

Tags: regex

What's the meaning of `{z\2}` in this regular expression, especially `\2`?

```
regsub -all -- (a+)(ba*) aabaabxab {z\2} x
```

I got this result:

```
(bin) 58 % regsub -all -- (a+)(ba*) aabaabxab {z\2} x
2
(bin) 59 % puts $x
zbaabxzb
```

How does the expression match `aabaabxab`?

Answer (score 0):

`{z\2}` tells your command to substitute all matches with `z` and *the content of the second capturing group* (`\2`).

The whole expression itself **doesn't** match `aabaabxab`!
What it matches are `aabaa` and `ab` at the end:

```
aabaabxab
^^^^^  ^^
```

Why? Because `(a+)(ba*)` means:

- one or more `a`s
  (`a+`)
- followed by a `b`
  (`b`)
- optionally followed by `a`s (zero or more)
  (`a*`)

So, the first match will be `aabaa` (seen from the beginning of the string). Now `aa` is the content of the first capturing group, `baa` is the content of the second. You now replace `aabaa` with `z\2`, thus `zbaa`.
See if you can figure it out yourself for the second match. :-)